Нужна ли запятая после "например" перед "чтобы" в данном предложении?
Мы изучали историю по разным причинам, например, чтобы знать свои корни.

Правильно:
Мы изучали историю по разным причинам, например чтобы знать свои корни.
Пояснение
Розенталь, пункт 5
5. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят слова особенно, в 
частности, то есть, а именно, например, а также, а просто и 
т. п. с присоединительным значением, то запятая после этих 
слов не ставится: На всякий случай имейте при себе 
удостоверение личности, например когда будете получать 
деньги по почтовому переводу; 

Примечание. Интересно отметить, что вводные слова перед подчинительным союзом обособляются. Речь идет о тех словах, которые не могут приобретать присоединительное значение. Однако слово например может быть как вводным словом, так и присоединительным союзом.
7. Если между главной и придаточной частями 
сложноподчиненного предложения стоит вводное слово, 
то оно выделяется запятыми на общих основаниях: Он 
подумал, возможно, что я не хочу с ним встречаться; 
Если есть спрос на что-либо, значит, будет и 
предложение.

